# Python merge 'n' cells in excel based on condition

Tags: python, excel, python-3.x, merge

I have an excel where there are values in row 1 from column 1 to column 15. Each cell value in the end has a number.

I would like to create another row which merges cells based on the ending number and puts that corresponding text in the merged cell. But the row values still needs to maintain the order.

For example `A1=ABC3`, `B1=ABC5`, `C1=ABC`4 and so on. Now I would like to create in row 2 a merge of first 3 cells for and place `ABC3`. I need to create 5 merged cells next in the same row 2 to place `ABC5`. After that 4 Merged cells in the same row and place `ABC4` and so on. Any thoughts how to implement this ?

Answer (score 0):

This can be accomplished with the [`openpyxl`](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/) module. If you're not familiar with it yet, then doing some of the [tutorials](http://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/default/tutorial.html) would be a good start.

Comment: Yes i did using openpyxl. But i think i made it too complicated :-). It does work but too much procedural and reusability is zero.  So was checking if there are better ways.

Comment: Ah, so you already have some code. Excellent! Could you please edit your question to include this code? This will make it much easier for people here to understand your problem and to help you. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks.